# How to set to XAML property a property value from another class

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to set property value from another class to XAML UI element property .
I have XAML and static class called "Config". 
In Config class I have public static class Theme. 
In the class Theme I have property primaryColor. 
So I need to set primaryColor to UI element in XAML.

I tried x:Static, but it doesnt work for me, cause the field in the Theme class is not static.

XAML:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor={x:Static config:Config.CurrentTheme.primaryColor}></StackLayout>
```

Config.cs:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static Theme CurrentTheme { get; set; }
}
```

Theme.cs:

```
public class Theme
{
    public Color primaryColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#1D1E1F");
    public Color secondaryColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#252625");
    public Color grayColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#2F2F2F");
    public Color lightGrayColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#626261");
    public Color goldColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#CAA440");
    public Color lightGreenColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#28A745");
    public Color darkRedColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#F0373A");
}
```

Comment: Boga, have you ever tried using the SETTER Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **Static** to **Theme.cs** , then can be used in Xaml :

```
public static class Theme
{
    public static Color primaryColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#1D1E1F");
    public static Color secondaryColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#252625");
    public static Color grayColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#2F2F2F");
    public static Color lightGrayColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#626261");
    public static Color goldColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#CAA440");
    public static Color lightGreenColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#28A745");
    public static Color darkRedColor { get; set; } = Color.FromHex("#F0373A");
}
```

**Xaml** :

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Theme.grayColor}"></StackLayout>
```

Don't forget to add **local** reference in xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourprojectNameSpace"
```

===================================Update====================================

If want to change color with binding property by viewmodel , have a try with `IValueConverter`:

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string valueAsString = value.ToString();
        switch (valueAsString)
        {
            case (""):
                {
                    return Color.Default;
                }
            case ("Accent"):
                {
                    return Color.Accent;
                }
            default:
                {
                    return Color.FromHex(value.ToString());
                }
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Config.cs` should be modified as follow:

```
public class Config : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string mycolor;

    public string MyColor
    {
        get { return mycolor; }
        set
        {
            mycolor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyColor");
        }
    }

    public Config (){
        mycolor = "#00FF00"; // can set a defalut color here
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And in Xaml :

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding MyColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"></StackLayout>
```

Finally , `ContentPage` need to bind Model `Config.cs`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Config config = new Config();
        this.BindingContext = config;

        //MyColor can be modified runtime
          config.MyColor = "#00FF00";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already know it, thank you. But I need this class without static fields. My question is how to bind field of class object in Config.cs (like in the example above) to my xaml stacklayout background color.

Comment: @Boga Maybe mistaking your want , I have updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

When you read about `x:Static` it directly says:

`x:Static` accesses one of the following:

- a public static field
- a public static property
- a public constant field
- an enumeration member.

since your properties do not meet the criteria mentioned above it does not work!

Comment: Got it, thank you.
Do you know how to solve this task in my situation, not using x:Static?

Comment: why are you not keeping these theme-related things as `const's`